# python error trying to install mps-youtube

Tags: python, youtube, pip

I try to install the software mps-youtube using this command

```
~$ sudo -H pip install mps-youtube
```

and I get the following result

```
    Collecting mps-youtube
  Using cached mps-youtube-0.2.7.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Mps-youtube requires python 3.
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Q3kVAJ/mps-youtube/
```

Where does the error come from and what can I do to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: As the error message clearly indicate, you should have `python 3` installed on your system if you want to install `mps-youtube`.

Comment: When you type `python3` in bash and press enter, what you get?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the message indicates you need Python 3. This should be installed by default, so that's fine. The problem is you are using `pip` which most likely links to `pip2` which is for Python 2. So try the same command using `pip3`:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install mps-youtube
```

It's possible you have to install `pip` for Python 3 first:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: Python3 is already installed.
I think the error message is only the line «Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error…» ~$ python3 Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux

Comment: @drjoe Did you at least try what I suggested? Depending on which `pip` you use is related to which Python version.